# Difference between int and double in C++ Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++, double, int

I am making a simple program which abstracts complex numbers and complex number operations. I started out with integer data types for my imaginary and real aspects of my complex numbers because of my vast ignorance when, after coding addition, subtraction and multiplication successfully, I realized that for division I would need to use doubles. When I switched to doubles I got bad results from my previous three calculations which worked wonderfully when the values were stored as ints. Can someone please explain to me what is so fundamentally different about ints and doubles in c++ that makes my code work fine for int but die when I try using doubles?

I have pasted my code for reference.

```
 #include "Complex.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


Complex::Complex(){
    real = 0;
    imaginary = 0;
}
Complex::Complex(double givenReal, double givenImaginary)
{
    real = givenReal;
    imaginary = givenImaginary;
}
double Complex::getImaginary(){
    return imaginary;
}
double Complex::getReal(){
    return real;
}
double Complex::getMagnitude(){
    //magnitude = sqrt(pow(real,2)+pow(magnitude,2));
    return magnitude;
}

Complex Complex::operator+(Complex n){
    Complex j = Complex();
    j.real = real + n.real;
    j.imaginary = imaginary + n.imaginary;
    return j;
}
Complex Complex::operator-(Complex n){
    Complex j = Complex();
    j.real = real - n.real;
    j.imaginary = imaginary - n.imaginary;
    return j;
}
Complex Complex::operator*(Complex n){
    Complex j = Complex();
    j.real = (real * n.real)-(imaginary * n.imaginary);
    j.imaginary = (real * n.imaginary) + (imaginary * n.real);
    return j;
}
Complex Complex::operator/(Complex n){
    Complex j = Complex();
    j.real = ((real * n.real) + (imaginary * n.imaginary))/(n.real*n.real + n.imaginary*n.imaginary);
    j.imaginary = ((imaginary*n.real)-(real * n.imaginary))/(n.real*n.real + n.imaginary*n.imaginary);
    return j;
}

int main(){

    Complex a = Complex(1, 3);
    Complex b = Complex(4, 8);
    Complex c = a+b;
    printf("Adding a and b\nExpected: (5,11)\nActual: (%d,%d)\n",c.getReal(), c.getImaginary());
    c = a-b;
    printf("Subtracting b from a\nExpected: (-3,-5)\nActual: (%d,%d)\n",c.getReal(), c.getImaginary());
    c = a*b;
    printf("Multiplying a and b\nExpected: (-20,20)\nActual: (%d,%d)\n",c.getReal(), c.getImaginary());
    c = a/b;
    printf("Dividing a by b\nExpected: (.35,.05)\nActual: (%d,%d)\n",c.getReal(), c.getImaginary());
    system ("pause");
}
```

Output:

Adding a and b
Expected: (5,11)
Actual: (0,1075052544)
Subtracting b from a
Expected: (-3,-5)
Actual: (0,-1073217536)
Multiplying a and b
Expected: (-20,20)
Actual: (0,-1070333952)
Dividing a by b
Expected: (.35,.05)
Actual: (1610612736,1071015526)

Comment: [What every programmer should know about floating point arithematic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: It's not that the values are being rounded wrong, I am getting what look to me like address spaces or something for the results. I'll put my output in my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What every C/C++ programmer should know about `printf` format specifiers are: `%d` is for `int`, `%f` is for `double`.

Comment: Apt to mention that not using a proper format specifier in functions such as `printf` and `scanf` results in Undefined Behavior & it is always the users responsibility to ensure that proper types are specified for such functions.